# Variables from one js file are not recognized

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

I'm loading some scripts on my website, but on one of test machines (using IE10) one of the scripts is not working.

```
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
   <script src='MF.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src="RTUMS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My website loads the google map api and I use two scripts to work with it, the MF with my functions is working fine on IE10 (the functions are called without any problems), but I have some variables declared on the RTUMS file, and they're undefined when used on any function.

```
   var rtuName = [];
   var rtuLat = [];
   var rtuLng = [];
   var rtuAlIcon = [];
   var rtuNmIcon = [];
   rtuName[2]="RTU 2";
   rtuLat[2]=-23.558401182216773;
   rtuLng[2]=-46.64146900177002;
   rtuAlIcon[2]="";
   rtuNmIcon[2]="";
```

Any hint on why this script is not working on IE10, when there's no problem on any other browser/version? Thanks!

Comment: Did u check the browser console for errors?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console? If there's an error in a script, the effect can by like what you describe..

Comment: Please, post the contents of both of your files.

Comment: Yes, i've checked for errors. Also, if i copy the script from the RTUMS file to the MF.js it works without problems, but i can't do it because this file need to be updated (from a script running on the server)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-ordering your script tags?

```
<script src="RTUMS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src='MF.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```